How can I format automatically an ion-input like accounting.js in Ionic?
I am using Ionic with Angular and have an ion-input for entering a discount amount. I want to format the input similar to how accounting.js (enter link description here)formats numbers, with specific decimal places and a percentage symbol. Here's my current code:
<ion-input
        #amountInput
        class="input-field"
        style="--padding-end: 20px; text-align: end;"
        placeholder="Amount"
        [(ngModel)]="discountAmount"
        (ngModelChange)="onDiscountAmountChange($event)"
        type="text">
        <p slot="end"></p>
      </ion-input>


https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#input-masking
